# Not show if empty in PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I´m adding extra fields in Joomla articles, and I want to not show that new fields (and "li") if there are empty:

From this

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <?php echo $this->item->direccion; ?>  
      <a href="<?php echo  $this->item->urlMap; ?>" target="<?php echo $this->item->targetMap; ?>">Mapa</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

To something like this:

```
 <ul>
   <li "if MOLA is empty not show this li">
      <?php echo $this->item->MOLA; ?>  
      <a href="<?php echo  $this->item->urlMap; ?>" target="<?php echo $this->item->targetMap; ?>">Map</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: `<?php if (...) : ?>...<?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `if` condition before you `<li></li>` and check if variable is not `empty`

```
 <ul>
   <?php if(!empty($this->item->MOLA)) { ?>      
   <li>
      <?php echo $this->item->MOLA; ?>  
      <a href="<?php echo  $this->item->urlMap; ?>" target="<?php echo $this->item->targetMap; ?>">Map</a>
   </li>
   <?php } ?> 
 </ul>
```

Comment: it gives me an error in your second line

Comment: @BizarriaesspumosaStudio sorry a typo, a semicolon not intended to be there, fixed

Comment: @BizarriaesspumosaStudio can you read the error ? srsly dont write php if you cant even understand the syntax :P try js first...

Comment: Weeee... Perfect! it works. I´m learning very slow... sorry...

Comment: @BizarriaesspumosaStudio i'm glad it works, don't forget to accept answer to help people in the future with similar problems!